# Sending trace info in Jest API tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, trace, web-api-testing

I'm testing a live web app using Jest.  The app consists of several services internally, and requests from the UI are all connected with trace information for observability. I'd like to include trace information in the API calls that tests make to vastly improve the debugging process.

The problem is that this trace information needs to be correlated to the tests by name somehow, so the trace IDs need to be available both within the test and to some post-test scope, like an `afterEach` method or a custom Reporter.  Can I achieve this in Jest without resorting to globals or other hacky solutions?

My background is in Scalatest, where passing this kind of data around is a first-class feature.

Comment: You may likely want to interact with tests in custom environment, handleTestEvent is available in Jest Circus and it provides data on currently running test. Environment class and a test can interact via env instance (`this.global` in env, `global` in test). Environment class and a reporter can interact via globals (`global` in env and reporter). It's not hacky to use globals at this point.

Comment: I was able to use `jest-circus` events to send the trace info to tests, but `global` values don't seem to reach the reporter from the env.  Can you expand this comment into an answer so we can continue the discussion there?

Answer (score 1):

Custom environment can inject into test lifecycle in [Jest Circus runner](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/jest-circus) and communicate with a reporter via runner global scope, e.g.:

*jest-global-setup.js*

```
export default async (globalSetup) => {
  global.runnerState = 0;
};
```

*jest-custom-environment.js*

```
export default class CustomEnvironment extends Environment {
  async setup() {
    // before all tests
    global.runnerState++;
    await super.setup();
  }

  async teardown() {
    // after all tests
    global.runnerState++;
    await super.teardown();
  }

  async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
    if (event.name === 'test_done') {
      // after each test
      // global is runner scope while this.global is test scope
      global.runnerState++;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

*jest-custom-reporter.js*

```
export default class CustomReporter {
  onTestResult(test, testResult, aggregatedResult) {
    console.log('Runner state:', global.runnerState);
  }
}
```

Comment: `global.runnerState` isn't accessible from the `CustomEnvironment` when I try the equivalent in my code.  Is there anything I could be missing?  My current code looks almost exactly like this.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, considering that all of these files were correctly specified in Jest config. What exactly does isn't accessible mean in your case? Did you try exactly this code?

Comment: When I increment `global.runnerState` in `handleTestEvent`, the changes aren't reflected in the logs printed by the reporter.  My current code is identical to this with the exception that my environment extends `NodeEnvironment`.  I know that each of these files are running.

Comment: The answer is fully workable, everything that's set in environment `handleTestEvent` `test_done` is available in reporter `onTestResult`, I don't see how this can be different, given that `onTestResult` is guaranteed to run after `test_done`, and `global` is same in both places. Tested with jest@26.0.1 and jest-circus@26.2.2. Please, provide a way to reproduce your current problem. Double check that you use Circus and handleTestEvent really runs.

Comment: `handleTestEvent` is definitely running in my code, it's injecting stuff into `this.global` that is available in the tests.  I'm using 26.2.2 for `jest` and `jest-circus`.  The only other difference I can think of is that I'm using the `projects` config option to run my tests.  I'll try to start a project from scratch and produce a minimal example of the issue.

Comment: On a whim I added the `--runInBand` flag and everything worked as expected.  I have several test files, so I'm guessing Jest is creating multiple threads and global state isn't being preserved.  Not sure how to progress from here, I don't want to use this flag for performance reasons.

Comment: It appears accessing global state this way is considered a bug and the "sandbox" behavior is correct: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5731